# how do you check if a namespace exists at all?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

We can list all the namespaces with the following method:

```
public static class NamespaceGetter
{
    public static IDictionary<string, string> Get(string xml)
    {
        XPathDocument x = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(xml));
        XPathNavigator foo = x.CreateNavigator();
        foo.MoveToFollowing(XPathNodeType.Element);
        return foo.GetNamespacesInScope(XmlNamespaceScope.All);
    }
}
```

However, if the `string xml` parameter has no namespace defined, then this method will throw.

For example, the following payload will cause an exception

```
<MyXml>
  <Cars>4</Cars>
  <Burgers>3</Burgers>
</MyXml>
```

**How do you check if a string has an XML namespace defined AT ALL?**

Output for the above will return:

[image]

This really makes no sense.

Comment: `The prefix xml is by definition bound to the namespace name http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace. It MAY, but need not, be declared, and MUST NOT be bound to any other namespace name`.  You could just exclude http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace, or the prefix xml - in practice its unlikely to be explicitly defined, and if it is, so what?

Comment: when you are reading a string into your domain, hoping that it will be XML, and if not, taking steps to form valid XML, it's an obstacle when external libraries are adding namespaces to your object without you knowing, that's what.

Comment: I don't get an exception when I try the code with the sample. There is a value for `XmlNamespaceScope` that excludes XML and it still doesn't return an exception, just an empty `Dictionary`. What exception do you think is thrown by the code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK.

But your XML string is invalid: the exception thrown is:

```
The 'MyXml' start tag on line 2 position 4 does not match the end tag of 'MyXML'
```

XML is case-sensitive.

Comment: i've added a bit more info